# Как взять строку таблицы с помощью phpQuery?

Tags: php, html, парсер

Голову ломаю, помогите разобраться. Есть html-страница с данными в таблице:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><b>1</b></td><td><b>2</b></td><td><b>3</b></td><tr>
    <tr><td><b>a</b></td><td><b>b</b></td><td><b>c</b></td><tr>
    <tr><td><b>aa</b></td><td><b>bb</b></td><td><b>cc</b></td><tr>
</table>
```

С помощью phpQuery нужно получить значения в тегах b исключив первую строку. Пытаюсь делать так:

```
$line = $cat_page_child->find('table > tr');
foreach ($line as $l_link){
    $ln = pq($l_link)->html();
    $mas_cat_child[]=$ln;    
}
print_r($mas_cat_child);
```

Вроде получаю все строки, но вот как дальше вытащить начиная со второй строки содержимое b? А если нужно получить не все b, а выборочно? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($line as $key => $l_link) {
    if ($key == 0) {
         continue;
    }
    $ln = pq($l_link)->html();
    $mas_cat_child[]=$ln;    
}
```

Возможно для выборки определённых значений в **b** тэге вам понадобятся регулярные выражения